# What is a separable closure? And why the standard definition of algebraic closure is defind as so?

Tags: field-theory, definition

Instead of defining it as a subfield of algebraic closure, what would be the natural way to define it?

Here's what I figured out:

> Let $F$ be a field and $E$ be an extension field of $F$.
>
> Then, $E$ is called a separable closure of $F$ iff $E/F$ is separable and for any separable extension $L$ of $E$, $L=E$.

Is this a correct definition? So that a separable closure means a maximal separable extension?

Secondly, I'm now curious why the standard definition of algebraic closure is defined so. Here is the standard definition of an algebraic closure.

> Let $F$ be a field and $E$ be a field extension of $F$.
>
> Then, $E$ is called an algebraic closure of $F$ iff $E/F$ is algebraic and $E$ is algebraically closed.

Rather than the above definition, I think the below one is more natural:

> Let $F$ be a field and $E$ be a field extension of $F$.
>
> Then, $E$ is an algebraic closure of $F$ iff $E/F$ is algebraic and for any algebraic extension $L$ of $E$, $L=E$.

Under this definition, one can see "closure" merely means a maximal object in a partially ordered category, hence I think this is more natural.. What's a reason for the standard definition is defined as so?

Comment: `closure` is also more than reminiscent of …`closed`, and you may add any adverb you please.

Comment: @Bernard Is my definition for a separable closure correct?

Comment: Absolutely. Sorry I forgot to say so.